# For videocasting, what is the best microphone?

Tags: microphone

I've done quite a bit of podcasting with an SM58.. Now, I'm doing videocasting, what's the best microphone to record sound? I want it to be more aesthetic: I don't want the microphone to be seen in the video -- I think that rules out dynamic microphones. It seems like a unidirectional condenser would be best? Any ideas of the best type of microphone to handle sound coming from a fixed direction, but preferably doesn't require obstructing the path of sight.

I've done some reviews, it seems like condenser microphones are really not made to be used more than 2 feet away from the sound source. They sound really over-gained and not isolated. I'm still undecided.

I found these videos to be useful:

In this video you can see the USB AT202 (which I imagine is not as good as my current sound set up)

> shows the AT2020 in a similar application

In this video you can see the Sure SM93 in a similar setting. It's pretty unobtrusive and delivers an impressive result.

> shows the Shure SM93 in a similar application.

Someone help me decide!

Comment: Are you ruling out lapel mics for any reason?

Comment: Not ruling them out, they're not opportune because they still show up and it can suck having a lapel mike on a t-shirt, but I'm open to the suggestion. what kind of lapel mike?

Comment: 'YouTube' is irrelevant to the question so have removed it.

Comment: Are you trying to find out the best model, or just the proper type? I'm not sure if this is a [shopping recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) question or not. Such questions are off topic, but "explain this kind of thing to me" questions are [definitely welcome](http://avp.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: explain what kind of microphone gives me ideal sound from a fixed point 3-5 feet away from a camera, without being overly obtrusive (preferably not at all obtrusive) in the camera's line of sight?

Answer (score 1):

I really like the Blue Yeti, it's pretty darn cheap and it has a dial to change what type of mic it is so you should be able to use it for different projects
(like voice-overs, and podcasts).
It's less then $150 and here's a link  (holy cow now it's only $100 on amazon)

http://www.bluemic.com/yeti/
I own 2 and my girlfriend uses hers for professional voice over gigs and is super happy with it .

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use an sE X1. It's a large diaphragm cardioid condenser mic with a surprisingly flat frequency response for the price (the only peak is a slight jump of +3dB at 10kHz). I've left a link for a specs below:

[sE X1 technical specs](http://www.seelectronics.com/se-x1-microphone)

[sE X1 on GAK](http://www.gak.co.uk/en/s.e.-electronics-se-x1-large-diaphragm-condenser/29460) (£119) (it also prices the same on dv247)

[sE X1 bundle](http://www.gak.co.uk/en/s.e.-electronics-sex1-project-studio-reflection-filter-bundle/39946) Plus for an extra £70 you can get a pop-shield and reflection filter.

Of course this is not the only option. A [Rode NT2A](http://www.gak.co.uk/en/rode-nt-2a/5744) (£219) or [NT1A](http://www.gak.co.uk/en/rode-nt1-a-complete-vocal-recording-solution-free-boom-mic-stand-free-pop-shield-and-free-shockmount/31723) (£145) is always a solid bet for vocal recording as is the [Audio Technical AT2020](http://www.gak.co.uk/en/audio-technica-at-2020/809) (only around £80 if you're on a strict budget!). Plus I bet you could find better prices for each of these mics if you looked around a bit.

That's all I can really think of off the top of my head. Ask if you have any further questions :D

Comment: do you have any example of the sE X1 in use and how far away from the speaker do you position it? And, do you position it right behind the camera?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm currently working away from home so I don't have access to examples for you, however, it is a very internally quiet microphone, very good SNR. I only really record voice without video so position it quite close to the speaker - but I've also used it for ambient instrument recording (meters away from the sound source) which always gives a very detailed and clear recording :)

Comment: @Jazibobs: how do these mikes compare, let's say, to a SONY PCM-D50 ? ( http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/cat-audio/resource.latest.bbsccms-assets-cat-audio-latest-pcmd50.shtml )

Comment: @SkippyFastol - I've never used the Sony PCM-D50 so I couldn't tell you anything about it. Sorry :(

Comment: @Jazibobs: No problem. It's just the best mike I know !